# Value of variable gets lost outside a try-catch statement in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display some math for a school project using react and MathJax and MathJs,
the code is the following:

```
const InputForm = () => {

    let latex;
    let node;
    let inicial;
//    MathJax.typesetClear();

    let parenthesis = 'keep'
    let implicit = 'hide'
    
    //'sqrt(75 / 3) + det([[-1, 2], [3, 1]]) - sin(pi / 4)^2'
    
    const [inputExpressionText, setInputExpressionText, ] = useState(initial);
    
    function initial(){
      node = math.parse('sqrt(75 / 3) + det([[-1, 2], [3, 1]]) - sin(pi / 4)^2')
      latex = node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : ''
      console.log('Node en estado inicial:', node)
      console.log('LaTeX en estado inicial:', latex)
      
      return 'sqrt(75 / 3) + det([[-1, 2], [3, 1]]) - sin(pi / 4)^2';
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      //OnInput();
    },[inputExpressionText,])

    
  
  
  

    

const OnInput = function () {
  
  console.log(inputExpressionText);
  inicial = document.getElementById("input")
  node = null;

  try {
    console.log("antes de node initial", inicial.value);
    console.log("antes de node", node);
    node = math.parse(inicial.value)
    console.log("después de node", node);
    
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("No entro a node = math",   )
    console.log(err.toString())
  }

  try {
    // export the expression to LaTeX
    latex = node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : ''
    console.log('LaTeX expression dentro de funcion:', latex)

    // display and re-render the expression
    
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
  console.log("lates en fuera del try-catch",latex)
}
  console.log("lates xfinal",latex)
  console.log("inputExpressionText ", inputExpressionText)
    return (
        <table className=' table  justify-content-between  '>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <th>Expression</th>
                  <td><input type="text"  onInput={(e) =>{
                          setInputExpressionText(e.target.value);
                          OnInput()
                        }} id="input" value={inputExpressionText}/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th>Pretty print</th>
                  <td><PrettyInput latex={latex}/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <th>Result</th>
                  <td><Result input={node} /></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}

export default InputForm
```

the problem is in this part

```
try {
    // export the expression to LaTeX
    latex = node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : ''
    console.log('LaTeX expression inside function:', latex)

    // display and re-render the expression
    
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
  console.log("lates en fuera del try-catch",latex)
}
  console.log("lates xfinal",latex)
```

When latex variale gets the tex inside the function, the     `console.log('LaTeX expression inside function:', latex)` confirms it, console shows the corresponding tex value.

But called again right outside the OnInput function, it shows undefined breaking the code.

I've tried to used the proposed example mathJs in [here](https://mathjs.org/examples/browser/pretty_printing_with_mathjax.html.html) adapting it to a react component.

That approached worked only if added live while working with vite, but stopped working if reloaded as it says the dom it's not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

This is because the const only has context within the try block. If you want this to be accessible outside the block you need to declare it before the block and set it accordingly.

### Solution

There are two main ways to do this, either with state or let.

**Here's an example with useState:**

```
//make sure to import {useState} from 'react' to use this
//declaring the variable outside of the block will allow it to be used anywhere
[latex, setLatex] = useState('')

try {
    // export the expression to LaTeX
    setLatex(node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : '')
    console.log('LaTeX expression inside function:', latex)

    // display and re-render the expression
    
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
  console.log("lates en fuera del try-catch",latex)
}
  console.log("lates xfinal",latex)
```

**Here is an example with let** (*this will not persist like state though*, it will be dumped on every re-render)

```
let latex = ''

try {
    // export the expression to LaTeX
    latex = node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : ''
    console.log('LaTeX expression inside function:', latex)

    // display and re-render the expression
    
  }
  catch (err) {
  }
  console.log("lates en fuera del try-catch",latex)
}
  console.log("lates xfinal",latex)
```

---

### Update (3rd option)##

You could also do this with a function as well, such as:

```js
const Latex = () => {
 try {
    // export the expression to LaTeX
    return node ? node.toTex({parenthesis: parenthesis, implicit: implicit}) : ''
    console.log('LaTeX expression inside function:', latex)

    // display and re-render the expression
    
  }
  catch (err) {
     return 'Error'
  }
}
```

then you would use it like this:

```
const ExmapleComponent = () => {
  //can put latex function here or in a helper file 
  const latex = Latex()

  return <div> jsx here </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trying to use the result of an asynchronous call back to `OnInput` before it has been called - `latex` is still set to `undefined` by its declaration at the top of the `InputForm` function.

The solution is to trigger processing of `latex` and re-rendering from within `OnInput` after it has been called back, not immediately after the `const OnInput = ...` statement has been executed.

Comment: Oh, I feel kind of out my depth, yet I sounds important that I get understand this, I will look into it further later, by the time being the solution of kyle worked, still, thanks <3

Comment: React is not my specialty but notice that the  `console.log("lates xfinal",latex)` statement is not inside the `OnInput` function but follows immediately after its declaration. I now see that `latex` is initialized in `function initial`  - I suggest checking if `console.log("lates xfinal",latex)` shows the initialized value of latex or one updated in `OnInput` -  obviously not testing using the same data used for initialization.

Comment: Oh right, I think I get what you are saying, and you are actually kind of right, I say kind of because I don't get it completely yet as you said, something is rendering one step behind or something like that, because one of my states seems to be behind the rest. Definitely worth checking it out.

Comment: Ok, I'll leaved you with it. Suggestion for before submitting the project: remove the two console logs immediately following the declaration of `OnInput` or move them somewhere else, and use consistent indentation in the code - two or 4 space tabbing, not a mixture of both. Good luck and happy learning.